# How to perform condition based query using executeQuery() in Swift FMDB

Tags: swift, fmdb, select-query

**How can i perform below condition based operation in swift FMDB?**

let result:FMResultSet=database.executeQuery("select * from image where id = ?", withArgumentsInArray: nil)

Answer (score 0):

let result:FMResultSet=database.executeQuery("select * from image where id = ?", withArgumentsInArray: ["10"])

Comment: Please explain your answer as well.